Adding to a JavaFX XYchart using an array
I'm working on a visualization program for large data sets. The program works when written as follows:
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.get(0).size(); i++){
        Double n1 = nums.get(0).get(i);
        Double n2 = nums.get(1).get(i);
        Double n3 = nums.get(12).get(i);
        sendNumbers(n1, n2, n3);
    }
    setNumbers();
}

public void sendNumbers(double[] n2, double[] n3, double[] n5){
    seriesL.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(n5, n2));
    seriesR.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(n5, n3));
}

but the set I'm looping through to add numbers to the XYchart is an array of 64000 points, making the program quite slow. Is it possible to just add the array as a single action?

Create a List of XYChart.Data and then do series.getData().addAll(theList). You probably want to turn off chart animation too, if you haven't already. FWIW I'm not sure the chart API is designed for data sets that large.

Also consider [tag:jfreechart-fx] perhaps using FastScatterPlot, seen here in Swing but easily adapted.

Also, have a look at this. I think they designed it for large datasets.

@James_D I did some experimenting a couple years back adding gazillions of data points to a chart just to see how it would handle it.  I was pleasantly surprised at how well it coped.  Even the animation didn't choke.  I couldn't find work on this, but IIRC 64K data points would have been less than I tested.

@DaveB That surprises me a bit. It's been years, but I tried something similar a while back. The problem is that the chart API associates a node with every data point, which has obvious overheads. But maybe they have optimized it somehow.
